# Cassandra Bulk Loader never exits on a null pointer exception, so my calling shell script doesn't see the failure

Tags: linux, bash, java

I created a script that processes files in a loop, using a process call. I check the exit code  of said call to see if I should move the files (on success.) Problem is, that when the process fails with an exception, it never exits. How do I go about detecting the exception occurred, so I can make the script move on to the next files?

**Relevant part of script**

```
# Stream data
sstableloader -d $3 $tablepathfull

# On success, move data to target dir
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Error: Table failed - $tablepathfull"
else
    echo "Table OK - $tablepathfull"
    trgtdir="$2/$hostname/$keyspacename/$typename/$timestamp/$keyspacename/$tablename"
    mkdir -p $trgtdir
    mv $tablepathfull/* $trgtdir
    rmdir $tablepathfull
fi
```

If there is no 'official' way, is it perhaps possible to capture the output (see below) of the process call, and simply kill the process once/if the exception occurs?

**Exception output**

```
Exception in thread "STREAM-OUT-/XX.XX.XXX.88" Exception in thread "STREAM-OUT-/XX.XX.XXX.92" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$MessageHandler.signalCloseDone(ConnectionHandler.java:249)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:375)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$MessageHandler.signalCloseDone(ConnectionHandler.java:249)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:375)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: That exception should be terminal. Please report this as a bug.

Comment: @DanD. To who, and where? And isn't it possible the java application that I am calling prints the exception, but then doesn't exit? Sounds probable to me...

Comment: Can you see the process with ps after it gives that exception? It should be a child process to your script.

Comment: @Radoo I can see it in htop

Comment: Then it should be a bug of that Java app. The normal behaviour of a simple process tool after throwing an exception is to exit with an error code. Why would it be locked forever doing nothing?

Comment: @Radoo I have absolutely no idea, maybe it's just bad design on their part. I'm just looking for a workaround because if I have to monitor this manually, it's going to be a long night.

Comment: @natli, is there an output on success or failure? I mean, not the exit code?

Comment: @Radoo If all goes well, the process closes and the exit code is 0. But no explicit output like 'success' or something, no. A non-exception error has exit code 1.

Comment: I don't have time now to give you the whole answer, but I'll come back in a few hours with the whole thing. The main idea is using that java app in a subprocess, and send and check the output from a file. In that file you'll also print the exit code in case of non-exception.

Comment: @Radoo Sounds like an excellent plan, looking forward to the details. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround I could come with is using subprocesses and files:

```
TEMP_FILE='/tmp/some_file.txt'

function load_table() {
  if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    printf "1" > "${TEMP_FILE}"
    return 1
  fi

  local param1="$1"
  local table_full_path="$2"
  local exit_code

  # Stream data
  sstableloader -d "${param1}" "${table_full_path}" >> "${TEMP_FILE}"
  exit_code=$?

  printf "\n%s" "${exit_code}" >> "${TEMP_FILE}"
}

function is_process_running() {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    return 1
  fi
  local process_id="$1"

  ps aux | sed -r 's/[ ]+/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep -q "${process_id}"
  return $?
}

function exceptions_count() {
  local count=$(tail -10 "${TEMP_FILE}" | grep -c "Exception")
  return $count
}

…

load_table "$3" "${tablepathfull}" &

# Given you have one subprocess only.. get the pid of the first subprocess in the list
job_pids=( $(jobs -p) )
load_table_job_pid=${job_pids[0]}

while is_process_running "${load_table_job_pid}" && exceptions_count -eq 0; do
  sleep 5
done

exit_code=0
if is_process_running "${load_table_job_pid}"; then
  local load_table_job_gid=$(ps x -o  "%p %r %y %x %c " | sed -r -e 's/[ ]+/ /g' -e 's/^[ ]+//g' | grep -E "^${load_table_job_pid} " | cut -d' ' -f2)
  kill -TERM -$load_table_job_gid >/dev/null 2>&1
  exit_code=1
else
  exit_code=$(tail -1 "${TEMP_FILE}")
fi

rm -f "${TEMP_FILE}"

# Your code
# On success, move data to target dir
if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: Table failed - $tablepathfull"
else
    echo "Table OK - $tablepathfull"
    trgtdir="$2/$hostname/$keyspacename/$typename/$timestamp/$keyspacename/$tablename"
    mkdir -p $trgtdir
    mv $tablepathfull/* $trgtdir
    rmdir $tablepathfull
fi
```

You can improve the code by adding a retry count or something.

Comment: Retry isn't going to do any good, since the exception seems to occur if there's something wrong with the table files. I'll test this script  & accept the answer as soon as the issue occurs again, but it looks good & taught me a thing or two about bash, so thanks!

Comment: Oh, just out of curiosity; does `grep -c "Exception" "${TEMP_FILE}"` read the whole file every time? Because the output file can get quite big. If so, I'm going to replace it with `tail -n 10` because the last 10 lines would definitely include the Exception if it did occur.

Comment: Yes. Given the part of the code you wrote, I thought that java tool doesn't output anything. `local count=$(tail -10 "${TEMP_FILE}" | grep -c "Exception")`

Comment: I've updated the code with this last update.

Comment: It appears to be working just fine, but an exception hasn't occurred yet so I can't be 100% sure. But theoretically it should work so I expect no issues, thanks!

Comment: Well, you can add some verbosity, by printing out the whole temp file at the end, to see if the exit code was caused by the Exception or not.

Comment: Hey, script is working just fine except for one issue; when killing our load_table subprocess, the actual sstableloader process is not killed along with it, any ideas on how to fix that properly?

Comment: You mean sstableloader spawns a subprocess of its own which isn't killed?

Comment: You'll have to kill all the child processes then, before killing the spawned process. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes

Comment: Note that i've updated the code 'sed -E' -> 'sed -r'. -E was for OS X, -r is for Linux.

Comment: I've updated the code to work with killing the group processes.